# HTML Password entry, type POST, not displaying in Google Chrome

Tags: html

I have Googled and have found issues with Chrome and HTML stuff but I cannot find anything specific to this issue. The code below for the password entry of a captive portal shows just fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer but nothing at all will appear in Chrome and other browsers like those on Android devices and Apple OSes.

```
<!-- Username: <input name="auth_user" type="text" value="guest">
<input TYPE="hidden" name="auth_user" type="text" value="guest">
<input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
Password: <input name="auth_pass" type="password" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)">   <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue"><br>
<br>Click the 'Continue' button! Do not hit the 'Enter' key!<br>
<!--   <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
<!--   <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue">
```

However, If I move the hidden 'Username:... line' to the third line from the bottom, it shows up just fine in at least Chrome. I cannot test this on a live system, so just wondering if what is below is a correct fix for my issue...

```
<input TYPE="hidden" name="auth_user" type="text" value="guest">
<input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
Password: <input name="auth_pass" type="password" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)">   <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue"><br>
<br>Click the 'Continue' button! Do not hit the 'Enter' key!<br>
<!-- Username: <input name="auth_user" type="text" value="guest">
<!--   <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
<!--   <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue">
```

Thanks in advance!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because you didn't close the HTML comment on the 'Username' line. Add `-->` to the end of that line to fix the problem. HTML comments are delimited by `<!--` and `-->`; they are not like `//` comments such that they do not stop automatically at the end of a line.

This is the fixed code (notice how Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting doesn't render the code all gray, as a comment, like the original):

```
<!-- Username: <input name="auth_user" type="text" value="guest">-->
<input TYPE="hidden" name="auth_user" type="text" value="guest">
<input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
Password: <input name="auth_pass" type="password" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)">   <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue"><br>
<br>Click the 'Continue' button! Do not hit the 'Enter' key!<br>
<!--   <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">-->
<!--   <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue">-->
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed end of html comment

html comment starts with `<!--` and ends with `-->`

you missed later one
ie.

```
<!-- Username: <input name="auth_user" type="text" value="guest" -->
```

Comment: Oh dear! Then the last two lines of my example are in error as well?

Comment: yeah sure... and if you want to add multiple lines in then try adding it in beginning and close it at end. make sure you remove '-' in between them